# Согласование дополнения с подлежащим, имеющим собирательное существительное "большинство"

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, согласование, собирательное-существительное

*Большинство твоих коллег испытывают невероятно скуку от ***своей серой однообразной жизни***.*

*Большинство твоих коллег испытывают невероятно скуку от ***своих серых однообразных жизней***.*

Грамматически второй вариант является более корректным, т.к. коллег много и у каждого своя жизнь, а не одна жизнь на всех; однако такой вариант, как вы видите, ну совсем не читается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Большинство твоих коллег испытывают невероятно скуку от своей серой однообразной жизни.**

[Розенталь Д.Э. и др. Справочник. ГЛАВА XXXVI](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm#%D0%B7_14)

Я думаю, что этот вопрос относится к следующей теме:

Розенталь §158. Употребление единственного числа в значении множественного и множественного в значении единственного

1. Форма единственного числа употребляется в значении множественного в ряде случаев:

3)      при указании на то, что **одинаковые предметы принадлежат каждому лицу или предмету из целой их группы или находятся в одинаковом отношении к ним (так называемое дистрибутивное значение),** например: Солдаты стояли с опущенной головой... (Пушкин); Ученики писали карандашом (не «карандашами»).

К примеру, в Нацкорпусе вст**речается только выражение *прожили жизнь*, но нет выражения** ***прожили жизни.***

У него был такой творческий навык ― размышлять о прошлом своих героев: кем и чем они были до того, как стали его героями, **какую прожили жизнь**? [Сергей Залыгин. Санный путь (1972)]

Comment: Так-то оно так, только мне кажется, общего правила нет. Солдаты стояли с опущенной головой, но с бритыми головами и небритыми лицами (пример мой).

Comment: Это означает, что правило  только разрешает замену числа в определенных ситуациях, но  это возможно не во всех случаях.  Как обычно, нужно учитывать сочетаемость слов.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю Розенталя. Стоять с опущенной головой, писать карандашом — устойчивые словосочетания (обстоятельства действия), а не просто "одинаковые предметы принадлежат каждому лицу".

Comment: Он объясняет,  почему  этих сочетаниях используется ед. число. Каждый солдат стоял с опущенной головой (одинаковый предмет), поэтому нет необходимости использовать мн. число, можно обойтись ед. числом.

Comment: А я думаю,  солдаты стояли (как?) с опущенной головой (или по стойке смирно), но стояли (с чем?) с бритыми головами. Те же головы, синтаксическая роль разная.

Comment: Я думаю, что здесь "и опущенные,   и бритые головы"  являются несогласованными определениями и входят в состав сказуемого.

Answer (score 2):

Первый вариант грамматически более правильный. Хотя бы потому, что вариант множественного числа - "жизней", менее употребителен и более просторечен. Он требует какого-то определяющего слова: "человеческих жизней","тысячи жизней". Думаю,в данном случае,это не является нарушением правил, но выглядит хуже. Смысл фразы прекрасно понятен и без такого уточнения.
Для примера, можно заменить слово "жизнь", словом "существование":
"Большинство твоих коллег испытывают невероятно скуку от своего серого, однообразного существования". Множественное число в этом случае употребляется ещё реже. В основном, в каких-то философских рассуждениях.

Answer (score 1):

В данном контексте слово *жизнь* употреблено в смысле "образ жизни". В этом случае употребление множественного числа является просторечием.